# rollup package splitting / code splitting

Tags: reactjs, rollup, rollupjs, code-splitting, npm-package

I am working on a components library (such as material-ui). I am using rollup for compiling.
For the moment I can generate a single package, and to import a component such as a button, I can do it like that :

```
import { Button } from "package-name";
```

Can I modify the rollup configuration to generate a separate package or chunk for each component.
In other word, can I split the big-size package in separate small-size packages (one for each component)
and use them in a way similar to this:

```
import { Button } from "package-name/Button";
```

I start looking to the [Code Splitting](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#code-splitting)...
But I am wandring if there is a known best practice to have this result?

Is there a specific way to write the rollup.config file ?

Answer (score 0):

To generate separate chunk/output for each component, you will have to provide an array of rollup config (multiple entry files of components). Then you can publish those output chunks as separate packages.

In case you just want to make your library tree-shake-able, then single package is also sufficient (yes even with just single output chunk). But the output format has to be `es` instead of `cjs` or `umd`.

Bundling with rollup only makes your library tree-shake-able but it also depends on your consumer application capabilities to tree-shake dead code in the final build.